# How widely supported is the accelerometer in Android devices?

Tags: android, accelerometer

We're developing an Android app that relies on the accelerometer for certain features. I'm wondering how safe it is to rely on the existence of the accelerometer and not provide alternative UI options for devices that do not support it (e.g. a button). My observation is that most "smartphone" Androids out there support it. Am I correct?

It would be nice if someone can point me to some data or stats for all Android devices out there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've personally never seen an android device without an accelerometer. The internet seems to agree on that aswell:

[Link 1](http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/do-all-android-devices-have-an-accelerometer-t10801.html)

[Link 2](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/fxzbl/do_all_android_phones_have_accelerometers/)